# How do I compare the values in 'Mono'?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor

Comparing the values in `Mono<Integer> a` and `Mono<Integer> b`, if the value in `Mono<Integer> a` is larger, I want to throw an error.

```
Mono<Integer> a = getA();
Mono<integer> b = getB();

if(a > b) {
 throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Comment: **What is your basis for comparison?**  Example: I can compare two strings by looping over the characters of each string, comparing them one by one, and if there is a mismatch, comparing the two mismatching characters.  Can you describe a similar process with `Mono<Integer>` that satisfies your specific requirements?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just want to compare the size of the `Integer` value in `Mono`

Comment: Is this what you're referring to? https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/929/reactive-programming-with-reactor-3/Mono

Comment: @RobertHarvey It seems different, but I solved it with the answer below.
Thank you for letting me know a good site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Mono<Integer> a = Mono.just(12);
Mono<Integer> b = Mono.just(10);

a.zipWith(b)
    .doOnNext(tuple -> {
        if (tuple.getT1() > tuple.getT2()) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }).subscribe();
```